# Replacing constant factors

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

**Goal**: I want to multiply all constant factors in an expression by 2.
For example,

```
4 x^2 (4 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 7 Subscript[c, 4])
```

should be transformed to

```
8 x^2 (8 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 14 Subscript[c, 4])
```

However, **I don't want the replacement to apply for powers (such as `x^2`) and subscripts.**

On my attempt to explicitly name the expressions that should be changed (which would be too much work anyway because it's not a generic solution) replacement also affects power and subscripts:

```
4 x^2 (4 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 7 Subscript[c, 4]) /. 2 -> 4 (* wrong *)
```

(A solutions that turns `Subscript[a, 2]` in `2 Subscript[a, 2]` would also be fine.)

Comment: See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html). It will explain how to write such a pattern.

Comment: The solution I came up with now is `expr //. {x^p_ -> x^p, Subscript[i_, j_] -> Subscript[i, j], n_Integer -> 2*n}`
Improvement allowed. I have installed Mathematica for 6 hours now and I am just starting to learn. Thanks

Comment: What do you want done with an implied constant of `1`? Should `x` become ` 2 x`?

Comment: Side note: Since you're just starting, you might be interested in point 3 [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999) among others.  Also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20213/4999) might be relevant, too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, Thanks for taking the [tour]. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. Your question has been answered, and there are [things to do after that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its good practice to wait 24hours for other answers before up-voting and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the explicit [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) operator with one that doubles:

```
expr = 4 x^2 (4 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 7 Subscript[c, 4]);

expr /. Times :> (2 ## &)
```

> ```
> 8 x^2 (8 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 14 Subscript[c, 4])
> ```

`##` is shorthand for [`SlotSequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html), and `2 ##` is `Times[2, ##]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace[expr, {d_ x^p_ -> 2 d  x^p, 
  a_  Subscript[exp___] -> 2 a Subscript[exp]}, All]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "protecting" some kinds of expressions, you could just explicitly specify that you only want to replace products with integers:

```
Replace[
  4 x^2 (4 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] - 7 Subscript[c, 4]),
  n_Integer a_ :> 2 n a,
  All
]
```

This way, you don't risk forgetting to protect some form of expression