# Simplifying algebraically

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Is there a way to derive an simplified expression from other equations.  Or create an alternate form such that the main equation takes other equations and manipulates the main function.
Here is what I have.
[image]

```
Subscript[ω, h] = Sqrt[Subscript[k, h]/m];
Subscript[ω, α] = Sqrt[Subscript[k, α]/Subscript[
  I, α]];
μ = m/(π*ρ*b^2);
Subscript[r, a] = Sqrt[Subscript[I, α]/(m*b^2)];
Subscript[x, α] = Subscript[S, α]/(m*b);
Subscript[E, 1] = (m + π*ρ*b^2)*z + 
Subscript[k, h]*w + (Subscript[S, α] - π*ρ*b^3*a)*
n + π*ρ*b^2*V*o + 
2*π*ρ*b*V*c (y + V*t + b*(1/2 - a)*o)
```

Comment: Please, have respect and copy-paste the code.

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: Can you describe an example simplification of E1 that you would like to see in terms of your five previous equations? If so then sometimes `Simplify[complicatedexpr, var==someexpr]` will sometimes be able to find `someexpr` in `complicatedexpr` and replace that with `var`, for example.

Comment: A 2D aerofoil utilizing the Theodrosen Theory to find the static divergence speed.  The Simplify command did not work.  I've done it by hand but there could be further simplification and I have more equations which need to be simplified that are much longer and since

Comment: If you can provide a much more concrete specific example, something like: Given this equation in Mathematica notation it should be able to make this specific simplification by replacing this with that, then perhaps someone can ask for more details and possibly give you a method of showing you how to get where you want to go.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now (and thereby earn a badge), 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Bill  Your suggestion, embodied as `FullSimplify[x + y, z == x + y]`, works.  But, `FullSimplify[x + y, a == x + y]` does not work.  Weird!

Answer (score 8):

I presume that you wish to eliminate some variables in the last expression in terms of variables defined in the other expressions.  Let me begin with two pieces of advice:

- Do not use subscripted variables.  They may look nice, but they can cause problems.
- Simplification is in the eye of the beholder.  Mathematica's idea of simplification, based on `LeafCount`, may not agree with the user's.

On this basis, rewrite the expressions as equations, named for convenience

```
eq1 = ωh^2 == kh/m;
eq3 = μ == m/(π*ρ*b^2);
eq5 = xα == Sα/(m*b);
eq6 = E1 == (m + π*ρ*b^2)*z + kh*w + (Sα - π*ρ*b^3*a)*n + π*ρ*b^2*V*o + 
    2*π*ρ*b*V*c (y + V*t + b*(1/2 - a)*o);
```

eliminate what I presume are the unwanted variables, and simplify the result.

```
FullSimplify[Eliminate[{eq1, eq3, eq5, eq6}, {ρ, kh, Sα}], b != 0 && m != 0]

(* E1 μ == m ((1 + c) o V - a (b n + 2 c o V) + (2 c V (t V + y))/b + 
            z + μ (b n xα + z + w ωh^2)) *)
```

If this is not completely simplified in the way you have in mind, you may need to play around with the code a bit, but this should give you some idea of how to proceed.  Good luck.

Comment: @Aeroelasticity More advice about `Subscript`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20213/4999