# Plotting a curve defined implicitly

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, implicit

I have defined the function `functiontoplot` using the following piece of code:

```
f1 = c*(S*A^2)/H - mu*A + ρa*Y;
f2 = c*S*A^2 - ν*H + ρh*Y;
f3 = c0 - γ*S - ϵ*Y*S;
f4 = d*A - e*Y + Y^2/(1 + f*Y^2);
eq = Solve[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0, f4 == 0}, {A, H, S, Y}][[3]];
jacobianmat = D[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, {{A, H, S, Y}}];
diffmatrix = DiagonalMatrix[{D1, D2, D3, D4}];
det = Simplify[Det[jacobianmat - μ*diffmatrix]];
der = Simplify[D[det, μ]];
ksquared = Solve[der == 0, μ][[1]];
c = 0.002;
mu = 0.16;
ρa = 0.005;
c0 = 0.02;
γ = 0.02;
ϵ = 0.1;
d = 0.008;
e = 0.1;
f = 10.0;
D1 = 0.001;
D2 = 0.02;
D3 = 0.01;
D4 = 10^-7;
det = Simplify[det];
ksquared = Simplify[ksquared];
eq = FullSimplify[eq];
functiontoplot = det /. ksquared /. eq;
```

`functiontoplot` depends on two parameters $\rho h$ and $\nu$. I know that it has a root approximately at the point where $\rho h=1.0011\cdot 10^{-5}$ and $\nu=0.04$. I've tried to plot the function using the following command:

```
ContourPlot[
 functiontoplot == 0, {ρh, -0.001, 0.001}, {ν, 0.03, 0.05}]
```

However, after waiting for a long time, I get an empty plot as an output. I know that plotting an implicit function is an expensive process, so I want to implement an accurate faster method to plot my function.

Until now, I have tried with the pseudo-arclength continuation method explained in the first answer here:

[Is there any predictor-corrector method in Mathematica for solving nonlinear system of algebraic equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104578/is-there-any-predictor-corrector-method-in-mathematica-for-solving-nonlinear-sys/104694#104694)

In particular, after defining the function `TrackRootPAL`, I use the following commands:

```
tr = TrackRootPAL[{functiontoplot}, {ν}, {ρh, -0.001, 0.001},
    1.0011*10^-5, {0.04}];
Plot[Evaluate[ν[ρh] /. tr], {ρh, -0.001, 0.001}]
```

Nevertheless, when it improves the initial condition, I get the complex number `ν[0]==0.0399995 +9.22304*10^-21 I`, so NDSolve is not able to keep working with the equation and, since it is a differential algebraic equation, there are no more methods available for NDSolve. I have even tried applying `Chop` to the initial condition but that then NDSolve needs to work with other complex numbers so I get warnings all of the time. Is there any solution for this using my approach or maybe another method to plot the curve I want to plot?

Comment: FYI, re `Subscript`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395, point 3. Also: ["Really the best way to use subscripts is to not use them."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/solve-with-v9-issues-with-subscript-overscript-superscript-etc/20213#comment61973_20195)

Comment: `functiontoplot` has a `LeafCount` around $5\times10^7$ and took over 90 sec. to evaluate *once*. -- And having `c` and `Subscript[c, 0]` is a bad idea (see prev. comment). Probably not a big issue here, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right! I removed all the subscripts from the script. However, the result is still the same.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have anything really helpful to suggest.  Possibly you could refactor (in CS lingo) `functiontoplot` through several functions, each computing a numerical step, instead of composing all of the symbolic expressions into a giant expression for `functiontoplot`.  I mean the number of lines of code above is fairly short, the two `Solve` being the only potentially long processes. But they're usually faster with fewer symbolic parameters. Something to consider if that's how the expressions get so large.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the problem, I think it is important. I simplified some expressions before evaluating `functiontoplot` and now the `LeafCount` of `functiontoplot` is approximately equal to $8\times 10^6$. When you talked about refactoring `functiontoplot`, what do you mean with CS lingo?

Comment: For your reference parameters, `eq` has 7 solutions and `ksquared` has 3.  How do you know that the `eq[[3]]` and `ksquared[[1]]` are the ones you want?  Are there any constraints on `{A, H, S, Y, \[Mu]}`?

Comment: That's true. `eq` refers to the equilibrium points of the system. I only want to work with the stable one for the parameter values I am considering at the beginning. The equilibrium number three is the only one that fulfills that condition. On the other hand, for the case of `ksquared`, I am taking into account the solution that has lets $\rho_h=1.0011*10^{-5}$ and $\nu=0.04$ to be a common solution to the equations $det=0$ and $der=0$. I am following that approach because I need to know the value of $\mu$ at each of the points of the curve I need to plot.

Comment: Do `{A, H, S, Y, \[Mu]}` need to be real? positive? something else?

Comment: A,H,S and Y need to be positive. \[Mu] only needs to be real.