# Derivatives and subscripts

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, subscript, notation

Is there a way to declare that subscripted letters are not functions of the letter? By default, this happens:

```
In[5]:= D[Subscript[t, 0], t]
Out[5]= (Subscript^(1,0))[t,0]
```

which I can understand but is slightly eye-roll-inducing.
Mathematical practice would like this t_0 to be constant.

Comment: You can use [Symbolize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html#378720807). There are already [a few questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=symbolize+subscript) about this.

Comment: [Point 3:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/46569) "Avoid subscripted symbols."  That said, try setting `Attributes[Subscript] = {Constant, NHoldAll}`.

Comment: Instead of using `Subscript[t, 0]` use `t0` and format it to look like `Subscript[t, 0]`, i.e., `Format[t0] = Subscript["t", 0];` Then `D[t0, t]` evaluates to `0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve with v9 (issues with Subscript, Overscript, Superscript etc)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/solve-with-v9-issues-with-subscript-overscript-superscript-etc)

Comment: This is a simple mistake?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variation of the following [idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246795/45431) where I fix a similar issue with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
$Notations = Alternatives[
    Subscript, Superscript, Subsuperscript, SubPlus, SubMinus, SubStar, SuperPlus,
    SuperMinus, SuperStar, SuperDagger, Overscript, Underscript, Underoverscript, 
    OverBar, OverVector, OverTilde, OverHat, OverDot, UnderBar
];

Unprotect[D];
D[a__] /; !FreeQ[{a}, $Notations[__]] := Block[{CompressedData},
With[{z=Unevaluated[D[a]] /. s:$Notations[__] :> CompressedData[Compress[s]]},
        z /; !MatchQ[z,_D]
    ]
]
Protect[D];
```

Then:

```
D[t Subscript[t,0] + t^2, t]
```

> 2 t + Subscript[t, 0]